# Row reduction with variables in augmented column

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across a problem where the linear system of equations were equal to different known quantities (represented as variables). After using Gauss-Jordan elimination, I came across two different scenarios...

1) In the last row, I had something like
0 = a + b + c (some linear combination of known variables)

2) In the last row, I had something like 2 = a + b + c (some linear combination of known variables)

I can interpret #1 as the system being inconsistent if a + b + c is not equal to 0, but I'm not sure how to interpret #2 in terms of free variables, pivot variables, etc.

Comment: What is the matrix? And $(2)$ appears to be a consistent system from what you wrote. For free variables you need to count the number of pivot on the rows and you need to count the number of columns and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first case you are right. In the second case I presume that the value 2 is associated to an unknown, in this case a+b+c is just twice the value of that unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Interpret the results in terms of *ranks* of the matrices: the minear system is consistent if and only if the matrix of the  augmented matrix has the same rank as the matrix of the  left-hand side .